# Comparing 2 lists and generating a new list with the differences

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to build a function that compares 2 lists of objects and returns a list with differences.

I will use it to check if data retrieved from a crawler is new by comparing it with data from my database.

```
   public static List checkForNewTweets(List timeline, List database) {
    List<TimelineTweet> newTweets = new ArrayList<>();

    List<TimelineTweet> timelineTweets = timeline;
    List<TimelineTweet> databaseTweets = database;

    for (TimelineTweet timelineTweet : timelineTweets) {
        for (TimelineTweet databaseTweet : databaseTweets) {
            if (!timelineTweet.equals(databaseTweet)) {
                newTweets.add(timelineTweet);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return newTweets;
}
```

This is not working at all, is there a way to make a recursive function for this?

Comment: side note: this function already exists within java Collection; check for `retainAll()`

Answer (score 0):

Your current logic would probably add all the `TimelineTweet`s to the `newTweets` list, since if `databaseTweets` contains at least two elements, at least one of them is not equal to a given element of the `timelineTweets` list.

Only after you finish comparing a `timelineTweet` to all the `databaseTweets` you can add it to the `newTweets` list (since that's the only way to know that the current `timelineTweet` doesn't match in any of the `databaseTweets`) :

```
for (TimelineTweet timelineTweet : timelineTweets) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (TimelineTweet databaseTweet : databaseTweets) {
        if (timelineTweet.equals(databaseTweet)) {    
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!found)
        newTweets.add(timelineTweet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

looking at your code I think only only want to remove the elements of the second list from the first and assign it to a third.

why dont you use timeline.removeAll(database) and then newTweets.addAll(timeline)

Answer (score 0):

Consider another approach.

```
public static <E> List<E> getDiff(List<E> list, List<E> list1){
    if(list.size() >= list1.size())
        return getDiffList(list, list1);
    return getDiffList(list1, list);
}

private static <E> List<E> getDiffList(List<E> list, List<E> list1) {
    List<E> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
    newList.removeAll(list1);
    return newList;
}
```

Please note this will report just different elements and any duplicates will be ignored.

```
List<String> strings  = Arrays.<String>asList("A", "B", "C");
List<String> strings1 = Arrays.<String>asList("A","B","D","C","B","Z","A");
```

Result list will be [D, Z]

Answer (score 0):

In case this is an option, you should have a look at the the Set classes of java, since containment is much cheaper to compute for those classes. I guess your `TimelineTweet`s are `Comparable` eg wrt their timestamp, thus can be used in a TreeSet, that allows lookup and insertion in log(n). A different option would be LinkedHashSet providing insertion order iteration and constant time operations or just HashSet if you dont care about ordering at all.

If you don't need the `timeline` again but are only interested in the new tweets, you can just remove all the items already in the `database`:

```
public static TreeSet<TimelineTweet> checkForNewTweets(
        final TreeSet<TimelineTweet> timeline, final TreeSet<TimelineTweet> database) {
    timeline.removeAll(database);
    return timeline;
}
```

Alternative: copy the `timeline`, afterwards remove the `database` entries.

```
public static TreeSet<TimelineTweet> checkForNewTweets(
        TreeSet<TimelineTweet> timeline, TreeSet<TimelineTweet> database) {
    final TreeSet<TimelineTweet> newTweets = new TreeSet<>(timeline);
    newTweets.removeAll(database);
    return timeline;
}
```

The operations are available for all collection classes in Java, but are faster for `Set`s.